# Firestore update document if I have a reference to it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am obtaining a document using the following code:

```
    db.collection("invites")
      .doc(inviteCode)
      .get()
      .then(async (docRef) => {
        // can I update the document I just retrieved here?
}
```

I want to update the document I just retrieved, e.g. incrementing an invitation counter on the document. Can I do that directly with the docRef, or do I have to explicitly call set(), e.g.:

```
db.collection("invites").doc(inviteCode).set({
            inviteCount: count+1
          });
```

What is the 'cost' in terms of read/write for this simple case for looking up an invitation code, and then updating a counter? Is there a more efficient pattern for this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do that directly with the docRef, or do I have to explicitly call set()

You can do it either way.  Your variable `docRef` isn't a reference, it's a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).  A [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) to the document is in the snapshot's [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref) property.

```
db.collection("invites")
    .doc(inviteCode)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        // snapshot.ref is a DocumentReference to the document
    }
```

`snapshot.ref` will be the same object as this, which doesn't require a query:

```
const ref = db.collection("invites").doc(inviteCode)
```

Every time you `get()` a document, it's one read.  Every time you `set()`, it's one write.

You can increment a field more efficiently without having to read the document by [using FieldValue.increment()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref).